# External image paths still doesn't show after adding it to external list on PhoneGap based application

Tags: ios, cordova

I have an app with PhoneGap for iOS. I want to show an image on my app with external url such as http://fatihacet.com/images/layout/logo.png.

When I include an image to my app I got an error which is **ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://fatihacet.com/images/layout/logo.png'**

I googled it, everybody says that "add your external links to ExternalHosts array on PhoneGap.plist and do not include protocol, just start with host name". Then I do that also I added some other records which starts with http:// or using wildcards but still I can't show images on the app. Where I miss something.

[image: screenshot]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: btw, the screenshot doesn't show the url starts with www... I have tried it and the result is same. Actually I tried almost all options. Definitely I miss something but I can't figure out it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue. What solved it for me was to CLEAN your project (select CLEAN in the PRODUCTS menu).

Simply use www.fatihacet.com.

Comment: Thanks man, it really works. I have been waiting this for two days.